# Pass object from a state to sub state in ui href

Tags: angularjs, ui-sref

I have grid which show the data related to customers and it has first column as hyper link to view details of that customer. Now on the grid i have all data required to show next page as api returns whole data.

My problem is how to pass this row data from first state to next. The next state has also param in its state.

So Ii need to pass two data from first state to second:

1. groupId for url/state
2. whole row data for populating second page.

State config:

```
$stateProvider.state('home.cust.groups', {
 url: '/groups',
 template: GroupTemplate,
 controller: 'GroupController',
 controllerAs: 'GroupController'
}).state('home.cust.groups.viewGroup', {
 url: '/view/group/:groupId',
 template: ViewRGroupTemplate,
 controller: 'ViewGroupController',
 controllerAs: 'ViewRGroupController'
});
```

HTML part:
I tried something like this which is throwing error

```
<td text="View Details" ui-sref="home.cust.groups.viewGroup({groupId : '{{row.groupId}}'}, {group : row})"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. Just pass the value from html in JSON format with all keys :

so the html will become :

```
 <td text="View Details" ui-sref="home.cust.groups.viewGroup({groupId : '{{row.groupId}}',group : row})"></td>
```